# changes to widget settings not showing up in individual pages pages until they're updated

Tags: plugins, widgets, options, cache

I'm using a plugin to add a widget to my sidebar. That widget has some settings that I'm still fiddling with in order to get things right...

[image: widget settings]

After adjusting the settings on the screen above and clicking 'save', I go back to view a page in my browser (all pages on the website use this widget) and the new settings are not reflected upon refresh as expected. I actually have to go into the backend and click 'update' for every page for which I want those new settings to take effect. It is becoming quite tedious and annoying to have to do this for several pages every time.

IS this by design or a bug with the plugin? If the former, is there a setting that will allow pages, while in development, to check the widget's config every time they load rather than caching it somewhere (which it what it seems to be doing?)?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Do you have any caching plugins enabled? If so, disable them and try again.